# How do I know when to stop training my CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've been training my CNN and got the following as results:

[image: Training results]

I just know that the training and validation accuracy needs to both be high, but are these numbers good enough? How do I know when to stop? Should I concern myself with the losses, or only accuracy? Which epoch shows the best result so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loss value implies how poorly or well a model behaves after each iteration of optimization. where as accuracy of a model is usually determined after the model parameters and is calculated in the form of a percentage.

Yes, training and validation should be high. Numbers always depend on subject area where we are dealing. In case of medical domain these numbers not good.

If you have serious class imbalance, your model will maximize accuracy by simply always picking the most common class, but this would not be a useful model. In this case cross entropy or log-loss would be a better loss function to optimize.

Generally the lower the loss the better a model unless the model has overfitted to the training data.

10th epoch is best where you got higher validation accuracy and lower validation loss.